# How do you test the performance of your website from multiple locations world-wide?

Tags: performance, testing, location

Following on from [How do you test the performance of a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53738/how-do-you-test-the-performance-of-a-website) :

What tools/sites/services do you use to find out the performance of your website from multiple locations around the world?

There are always complaints that sites are slow under certain circumstances (especially from physically-distant places), and it would be nice to be able to tell where it is particularly slow from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pingdom](http://www.pingdom.com)  are good, and quite cheap. They'll tell you if your site has suddenly started getting worse from one part of the world.

[Gomez](http://www.gomez.com) are excellent (they can test loading of all the images/css/js etc as well as the HTML itself, using the same pipelining rules as browsers use), and they can test not just from datacenter locations but end-user broadband connections -  but they're very expensive.

It's also worth using a tool like [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) to do basic analysis of your app and point out the things that are likely to cause problems over slow network connections.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Atatus](https://www.atatus.com):

https://www.atatus.com/browser-real-user-monitoring

Atatus's Performance Monitoring service tells you how your website really performs based on real user data.

Answer (score 1):

I used this site to check http://www.check-info.com , there have many tools for webmasters

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

http://www.dotcom-monitor.com/task_instant_test.aspx

It's a free service that tests from a limited list of locations worldwide, but it's a starting point at least.

Answer (score 0):

As you are talking about testing the site, I wonder is the site live or in your test environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can get users to test your site for very cheap prices by offering tasks on Amazon's [Mechanical Turk](http://aws.amazon.com/mturk/).